# If sum of $N$ natural numbers is less than $N+2$ then each of these numbers is less than $3$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Prove by contradiction.

If sum of $N$ natural numbers is less than $N+2$ then each of these numbers is less than $3$.

Attempt:

Assume if the sum of $N$ natural numbers is less than $N+2$ then each of these numbers is greater than $3$.

Let $x$ be the sum of $N$ natural numbers

$x < N + 2 $

Comment: No, the negation of "all the numbers are less than $3$" is not "all the numbers are greater than $3$".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Assume the sum of $N$ natural numbers is less than $N+2 \implies$ at least one of these numbers is not less than $3$.

Call that number $Y$. But then $Y+2 \ge 3+2=5.$ But $5 > N+2 \implies$ Contradiction!

$\therefore$ the sum of $N$ natural numbers is less than $N+2 \implies$ each of these numbers is less than $3$.

Answer (score 4):

You've got the negation incorrect: There would only have to be one that's greater than $3$ to make the original statement false. As a hint towards proving the statement, though, try:

Suppose that the first one was at least $3$. Then the sum of all of them is at least

$$3 + \underbrace{1 + \dots + 1}_{n - 1 \text{ times}}$$

Answer (score 3):

The statement that you’re trying to prove is that if $x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_N<N+2$, where each $x_k$ is a natural number, then $x_k<3$ for $k=1,\ldots,N$. You appear to be trying to prove it by contradiction, which is fine, but the negation of

> each of the numbers is less than $3$

is **not**

> each of the numbers is greater than $3$.

It is not even

> each of the numbers is greater than or equal to $3$.

The negation of

> each of the numbers is less than $3$

is

> at least one of the numbers is greater than or equal to $3$.

Assume that at least one of the numbers is $\ge 3$; the other $N-1$ numbers are at least $1$, so the total must be at least ... what?

(Note that this problem requires you to assume that *natural number* means *positive integer*. For many of us that’s false, because we include $0$ as one of the natural numbers.)